# run time of File.list()?

Tags: java, android

Does File.list() have a longer run time if there are more files in its folder? For example, if I have 5 files vs 200,000 files, I assume the later would take longer to return?

Thanks

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#list()

Comment: Of course it will take longer. How could it not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File.list() returns an array. Of course with a bigger array it will take more time to allocate and populate it. In addition any file system slows down with number of objects in a directory. IOW, yes with growing number of files in a directory File.list() will take more time.